# Recyclerview com analise JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-adapter

Meu código PHP gera o seguinte JSON:

```
{
"resposta":[
    {
     "cd_servico":"1",
     "ds_servico":"NOME SERVICO",
     "ITEMS":[
        {
          "ds_descricao1":"DESCRICAO SERVICO",
          "ds_descricao2":"DESCRICAO 2",
          "ds_valor":"120.00"
        },
        {
          "ds_descricao1":"DESCRICAO SERVICO",
          "ds_descricao2":"DESCRICAO 2",
          "ds_valor":"65.00"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
      "cd_servico":"2",
      "ds_servico":"SERVICO CATEGORIA 2",
      "ITEMS":[
          {
            "ds_descricao1":"DESCRICAO",
            "ds_descricao2":"DESCRICAO",
            "ds_valor":"90.00"
           }
           ]
      }
  ]
```

}

Estou tentando ler esse arquivo e listar os itens em um `recyclerview`, mas sem sucesso.

Segue meu código:

MainActivity.java

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Connect.URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ITEMS");

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListItem_Result_Parceiro item = new ListItem_Result_Parceiro(
                                    o.getString("cd_servico"),
                                    o.getString("ds_servico"),
                                    o.getString("ds_descricao1"),
                                    o.getString("ds_descricao2"),
                                    o.getString("ds_valor")
                            );
                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new Adapter_Result_Parceiro(listItems, ResultParceiroFrag1.this.getContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        RecyclerSectionItemDecoration sectionItemDecoration =
                                new RecyclerSectionItemDecoration(getResources()
                                        .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_recyclerview),
                                        true,
                                        getSectionCallback(listItems));
                        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(sectionItemDecoration);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ResultParceiroFrag1.this.getContext(), "Sem conexão com a internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("cd_parceiro", "1");
            params.put("app_chave", chave);//
            return params;
        }
    };//Acão acima envia um post para a url (Somente tipo String)////

    RequestQueue requesQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ResultParceiroFrag1.this.getContext());
    requesQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Adapter.java

```
private List<ListItem_Result_Parceiro> listItems;
private Context context;

public Adapter_Result_Parceiro(List<ListItem_Result_Parceiro> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.result_parceiro_frag1_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem_Result_Parceiro listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.HeadFrag1Parceiro.setText(listItem.getDs_descricao1());
    holder.DescFrag1Parceiro.setText(listItem.getDs_descricao2());
    holder.txtValorServ.setText("R$ "+listItem.getDs_valor());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView HeadFrag1Parceiro, DescFrag1Parceiro, txtValorServ;
    public LinearLayout LinearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        HeadFrag1Parceiro      = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.HeadFrag1Parceiro);
        DescFrag1Parceiro     = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DescFrag1Parceiro);
        txtValorServ     = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtValorServ);
        LinearLayout            = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearFrag1Parceiro);
    }
}
```

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem_Result_Parceiro {

private String cd_servico;
private String ds_servico;
private String ds_descricao1;
private String ds_descricao2;
private String ds_valor;

public ListItem_Result_Parceiro(String cd_servico, String ds_servico, String ds_descricao1, String ds_descricao2, String ds_valor) {
    this.cd_servico = cd_servico;
    this.ds_servico = ds_servico;
    this.ds_descricao1 = ds_descricao1;
    this.ds_descricao2 = ds_descricao2;
    this.ds_valor = ds_valor;
}

public String getCd_servico() {
    return cd_servico;
}

public String getDs_servico() {
    return ds_servico;
}

public String getDs_descricao1() {
    return ds_descricao1;
}

public String getDs_descricao2() {
    return ds_descricao2;
}

public String getDs_valor() {
    return ds_valor;
}
```

}

Verifiquei vários exemplos mas não encontrei a solução.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda dos amigos.

Comment: Se possível troque a imagem pelo código.

Comment: Alguma exceção ou erro especifico?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero editei a imagem pelo código.

Comment: @MaxFratane, acredito que o problema esteja na leitura dos "ITEMS", pois se eu modificar no php para gerar o json da seguinte forma: {
 "resposta":[{ "cd_servico":"1", "ds_servico":"NOME SERVICO"}]}, ele funciona bem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está na leitura do JSON. Você está considerando que o array `ITEMS` está no primeiro objeto da hierarquia, quando, na verdade, ele está no segundo.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray resposta = jsonObject.getJSONArray("resposta");
for (int i = 0; i < resposta.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject object = resposta.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray items = object.getJSONArray("ITEMS");
  for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject o = items.getJSONObject(j);
    ListItem_Result_Parceiro item = new ListItem_Result_Parceiro(
        o.getString("cd_servico"),
        o.getString("ds_servico"),
        o.getString("ds_descricao1"),
        o.getString("ds_descricao2"),
        o.getString("ds_valor")
    );
    listItems.add(item);
  }
}
```

Recomendo que você estude bibliotecas para conversão de JSON, como [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) e [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi). Com elas você consegue converter objetos JSON para POJOs, facilitando seu trabalho e evitando este tipo de confusão.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Leonardo, o código que vc postou funciona se eu retirar os itens "cd_servico" e "ds_descricao" que no caso estão fora do array "ITEMS", esse item "ds_descricao" eu queria que ficasse como cabeçalho no recyclerview dos itens que estão dentro do array "ITEMS".